# Loading Javascript with javascript_include_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

So I am a little lost on loading my javascript file when I am on a specific web page

**What I did:**

Took out `reguire_tree .` from Application.js because I read it will load every script we have all at once. 
Then I went to the HAML file that was created when I generated my controller and did this:

```
%p  From HAML!
- javascript_include_tag '/assets/javascripts/jstester.js'
```

and my jstester.js Javascript file is located under **assets->javascripts** folder and for now it just has something like:

```
document.write("from the script");
```

But it does not run my script now. What are the things I am missing or done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I got it working with the following code...but please let me know if there are better pracitces...  thanks

```
%p  From HAML!
= javascript_include_tag 'jstester'
```